# is there a roo 2.0 log4j add-on or example

Tags: logging, log4j, spring-roo

Is there a log4j add-on for roo 2.0  I see the tomcat has a log4j properties but nothing in roo to setup logging like the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Roo 2.0 generates Spring Boot default applications, so it uses the default Spring Boot configuration for the logging management.

Check the possibles Spring Boot logging configuration in the official documentation of Spring Boot:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Hope it helps,